# Subsetting a Data Frame based off the last time a value appears

Tags: r

I would like to subset a data frame according to the last time a value appears. The column is a Frequency table in chronological order. I would like to find the last time the value in the column is greater than the "Cut_Value". I would then like to subset the column such that it creates a new frame from the first value until 5 rows after the last appearance of the cutoff value.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: What have you tried? I'd think `z <- tail(which(dat$Frequency == Cut_Value),n=1)` would tell you the last occurrence of a value, and then `dat[seq_len(min(nrow(dat), z+5)),]` would give you the rows-subset.

Comment: @r2evans that worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample data and run-through, using `x` as your `Frequency`, then `cutoff` of 4, and following with only 2 rows (you'll use 5):

```r
dat <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=11:20)
cutoff <- 4L
(z <- tail(which(dat$x == cutoff), n=1))
# [1] 4
dat[seq_len(min(nrow(dat), z+2)),] 
#   x  y
# 1 1 11
# 2 2 12
# 3 3 13
# 4 4 14
# 5 5 15
# 6 6 16
```

So your code might be just

```r
z <- tail(which(dat$Frequency == Cut_Value),n=1)
dat[seq_len(min(nrow(dat), z+5)),]
```